# Symfony .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, symfony

I configured a test folder for websites in hostgator, so far I have no problems in some flatform like wordpress,magento,joomla, I did not even change any seetings in .htaccess to make it run. Recently, I am working on a symfony2 project and upload my test application in the test folder I created. This is how I create a test folder

```
  mywebsite.com/tests/wordpress_site(no problem)
  mywebsite.com/tests/joomla_site(no problem)
  mywebsite.com/tests/symfony2_site(403 forbidden error)
```

In my WAMP, I can accessed my symfony project

```
  localhost/symfony_site/web/
```

I did not touch the .htaccess since this is just a test site in local machine.
How would you configure a symfony2 project in this setup?

```
  mywebsite.com/tests/symfony_site
```

Answer (score 0):

It is almost impossible to create clean Urls when installing symfony in subfolder...

With Apache, the better solution is to use a VirtualHost which have tests/symfony_site/web as DocumentRoot, and to use the built-in .htaccess file (which uses url rewriting module, or if it not available, uses a 302 redirection to app.php/)

But If you can't add a virtualHost to your server, it is hard...

An other way is to add a .htaccess at tests/symfony_site and put `DirectoryIndex: web/app.php`
(https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html)

So you can have clean URLs... but **be careful with this solution:** the urls parsed by the router are **relative to your site root** (and not to symfony root...) so the router might be lost... (e.g if you have a root named `/test` you should rename it `/tests/symfony_site/test`... And it is the same for assets, you have to add the site directory, otherwise they will return a 404 error...

In my case, I just use existing .htaccess in web folder (or I create a new one with a DirectoryIndex Instead), so my app work with URLs like mywebsite.com/tests/symfony_site/web/

I hope this helped,

Vincent

Answer (score 0):

You can try typing the following code into the .htaccess file to the symfony root folder

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond $1 !^(img|files|images|favicon.ico|css|js|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} host.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !web/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1 [L]
```